# JS, Images not working properly in IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

When I deployed my project in IIS 7.5 in windows server 2008 R2 Standard, I noticed that the images and JS are not working properly even I Check the Static Content checkbox under World Wide Web Services / Common Http Features.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. can you share your code and/or the browser console logs/

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: please share your html and directory structure.

Comment: @MelZen 404 error means that your resource path is not correct. Please share your html showing how you are referencing the js and css files.